# Android - edittext illusion

Tags: java, android

I want to change the value of the EditText while typing on the virtual keyboard; my goal is to hide what the user types while displaying another text.  For example if I want to enter "Stack" but displaying "Overf" it's going to be like this: when "S" typed (and hidden in a buffer) it displays "O" then I type "t" and I get "v" etc.  In the end what I see on the EditText is "Overf" but in the buffer I get "Stack".  I tried TextWatcher but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `TextWatcher` by using `addTextChangedListener(TextWatcher watcher)` on the EditText. Then you should be able to override the TextWatcher's `afterTextChanged(Editable s)`  method to capture the new user input, store it in an internal string, and replace it with your own desired text.